# New lines query in a string in BigQuery

Tags: string, google-bigquery

I am trying to store compiled code (full queries with lots of breaks and new lines) in a table in BigQuery, but I am not able to create the full string when the query ends with a string with quotes.

For example:

```
select
   'this is a string',
   '''this is the string
   I am not
   able
   to store
   where field = 'string''''
```

I get the error

> Syntax error: Unclosed string literal at.

How can I solve this? I thought about checking if the string ends with a quote then removing it? However, the query wouldn't actually be completed.

Comment: What do you mean by "but it clearly doesn't"? Changing the query in your question to use `'''` at the start and end of the second string at least works in the BigQuery console. Please provide much more detail.

Comment: @JonSkeet apologies, I've just realised it works when running. I was confused because I couldn't see the string in green. I will add a better example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the following.

```sql
-- 1. escaping single quote
select
   'this is a string' AS string_column,
   '''this is the string
   I am not
   able
   to store
   where field = 'string\'''' AS multiline_string;
```

```sql
-- 2. using double quote for inner string
select
   'this is a string' AS string_column,
   '''this is the string
   I am not
   able
   to store
   where field = "string"''' AS multiline_string;
```

```sql
-- 3. breaking the line
select
   'this is a string' AS string_column,
   '''this is the string
   I am not
   able
   to store
   where field = 'string'
''' AS multiline_string;
```

Note that result of the third query ends with `\n`.  You can see the difference in the JSON output of the two results:

```
--1st query result in JSON format
[{
  "string_column": "this is a string",
  "multiline_string": "this is the string \n   I am not \n   able \n   to store\n   where field \u003d \u0027string\u0027"
}]
```

```
--2nd query result in JSON format
[{
  "string_column": "this is a string",
  "multiline_string": "this is the string \n   I am not \n   able \n   to store\n   where field \u003d \"string\""
}]
```

```
--3rd query result in JSON format
[{
  "string_column": "this is a string",
  "multiline_string": "this is the string \n   I am not \n   able \n   to store\n   where field \u003d \u0027string\u0027\n"
}]
```

Comment: thank you so much! I've gone with the third one adding the line break and works great.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE your_table
(
  col1 STRING,
  col2 STRING
);

INSERT INTO your_table (col1, col2)
VALUES ('this is a string', `this is the string 
I am not able to store`);
```

By using backticks, you can create a multiline string without any issues